# Add pages to PDF if certain criteria are met

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I am currently in the process of making a couple of forms on Adobe Acrobat, using imported data from Excel. In some cases, there is more data than there are spots on the PDF. I am trying to find a way to show/hide pages when an overflow page is needed. Is there any way I can do this??

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Look into creating page "Templates". Template objects are named pages within the document. These pages may be hidden or visible and can be copied or spawned. They are typically used to dynamically create content, for example, to add pages to an invoice on overflow.

You can use JavaScript to detect when you need the page and then show it and populate the data on that page.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FTemplate.htm